# How to select latest year's records using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server. I want to list the weekly information of a tutorial.

```
SELECT 
       tx.Lab, t.weekNo 
FROM 
       TutorialX tx 
INNER JOIN 
       Tutorial t 
ON 
       tx.id = t.id 
WHERE 
       t.tutID = @tutID AND 
       t.ProgramID = @pID AND 
       tx.Culture = @culture      
ORDER BY 
       t.WeekNo
```

Year field is in the table `Tutorial`.

This query brings me the records for all years. There are 14~16 records for each year. There will be 14~16 more new records for each year but I want to get only the biggest/latest year's records. For today, I want to get 2012's 14~16 records, next Year 2013's...

I have tried this but the result is the same using this query:

```
SELECT 
       tx.Lab, t.weekNo 
FROM 
       TutorialX tx 
INNER JOIN 
       Tutorial t 
ON 
       tx.id = t.id 
WHERE 
       t.tutID = @tutID AND 
       t.ProgramID = @pID AND 
       tx.Culture = @culture AND
       t.year IN ( SELECT MAX(year) AS y FROM Tutorial GROUP BY year)
ORDER BY 
       t.WeekNo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem removing `GROUP BY year` part in the inner query.

```
SELECT 
    t.weekNo, tx.Lab 
FROM 
    TutorialX tx 
INNER JOIN 
    Tutorial t 
ON 
    tx.id = t.id 
WHERE 
    t.tutID = @tid AND 
    t.ProgramID = @pid AND 
    tx.Culture = @culture AND 
    t.year IN (SELECT MAX(year) AS y FROM Tutorial) 
ORDER BY 
    t.weekNo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2005+, you can use the [ranking function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ...)` to do so:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  tx.Lab,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY year ORDER BY t.weekno) AS RN 
    FROM TutorialX tx 
    INNER JOIN Tutorial t ON tx.id = t.id 
    WHERE t.tutID = @tutID 
      AND t.ProgramID = @pID 
      AND tx.Culture = @culture      
)
SELECT Lab
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: This also brings me 1 record only.

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ - Can you please show some sample records from that table and the desired output? it will be very helpful thanks.

Comment: I have forgotten to type the week number. Allahu Ekber! Sorry. I am correcting it! Now you can see my query corrected in the question